# Ant-Design Switch in Form gives error due to value

Tags: reactjs, next.js, antd

I am dynamically creating Ant Design `Form.Item` in Next JS looking like this:

```
<Form.Item initialValue={initValue} key={property.key} name={property.key} label={property.name}>
    {component}
</Form.Item>
```

When the component is a Switch, it gets created like this:

```
component = <Switch defaultChecked={initValue} />
```

I get this error in the browser:
"Warning: [antd: Switch] `value` is not a valid prop, do you mean `checked`? "
[image]

I have tried different solutions such as removing the `initialValue` attribute from the Form.Item, as well as adding `valuePropName="checked"` and `getValueFromEvent={(value) => value ? value.checked : false}`

However, I always get this error-warning. Moreover, if I do remove `initialValue`, then the Switch is not included when I submit the form if the user does not update it.
I.e., its default value is ignored if only set using `defaultChecked={true}`, I necessarily need to include the `initialValue={true}`, otherwise the form may be submitted without the switch value/check being included.

How can I always submit the switch value and avoid this ugly console.log error message?

Comment: Just pass valuePropName="checked" to Form.Item. Do not pass getValueFromEvent. Second don't use defaultChecked to set initialValue. Use `Form` initialValues instead

Comment: Thanks Muhammad that actually did the trick. I am now adding valuePropName="checked" to the `Form.Item` only when it contains a Switch. I also removed the "defaultChecked" from the Switch and everything works fine. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to pass just defaultChecked if the value is true and not pass at all if the value is false. This is because checked attribute doesn't have value either you can pass or completely remove it.

```js
<Form.Item initialValue={initValue} key={property.key} name={property.key} label={property.name}>
    { initValue ?
     <Switch defaultChecked /> :  <Switch />
    }
</Form.Item>
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried doing exactly what you suggest here. It works insofar as the value being correctly submitted by the form. However, I still get the pesky error in the Chrome Inspect Console that says "Warning: [antd: Switch] `value` is not a valid prop, do you mean `checked`? ". 
The question is, how can I avoid this error?

Comment: Are you passing value as prop to Switch ? I think you need not pass it ?